# How can I adjust for negative eigenvalues?

Tags: correlation, data-imputation, eigenvalues

I wish to run a path analysis from a pooled correlation matrix that I have imputed using the maximum-likelihood procedure. There was considerable missing data. The resulting correlation matrix is:

```
                  [,1]       [,2]       [,3]        [,4]       [,5]        [,6]
       [1,]  1.0000000  0.3973131  0.3897562 -0.95475463  0.8304185  0.62680898
       [2,]  0.3973131  1.0000000  0.1832312 -0.72899798  0.8607616  0.43392841
       [3,]  0.3897562  0.1832312  1.0000000 -0.87403056  0.7268661  0.60550254
       [4,] -0.9547546 -0.7289980 -0.8740306  1.00000000 -0.9545632 -0.08212062
       [5,]  0.8304185  0.8607616  0.7268661 -0.95456317  1.0000000  0.89866540
       [6,]  0.6268090  0.4339284  0.6055025 -0.08212062  0.8986654  1.00000000
```

However, there are two negative eigenvalues from the matrix:

```
       [1]  4.2685858  0.9589848  0.8399586  0.5358510 -0.1439968 -0.4593835
```

After searching around, I have found some resolutions such as changing the eigenvalues to 0.

I was wondering whether there were other ways to adjust for this issue, or if forcing the negative eigenvalues to 0 is appropriate.

Many thanks

Comment: Negative eigenvalues from a correlation matrix means it isn’t a correlation matrix. Is your imputation correct? You must constrain your imputation to give a positive definite matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `nearPD()` function from the `Matrix` package to get the nearest (in Frobenius norm) positive definite matrix to your imputed correlation matrix. Set the flag `corr = True` to ensure that the main diagonal is 1.